# apache regex and proxypassmatch

Tags: regex, linux, url-rewriting, apache2, proxypass

I'm using apache and need to proxy my requests like this:

```
<LocationMatch "/133/2001">
      ProxyPass http://myserver.com/jtw/239.192.251.133:2001 
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/134/3001">
      ProxyPass http://myserver.com/jtw/239.192.251.134:3001 
</LocationMatch>
<LocationMatch "/135/5001">
      ProxyPass http://myserver.com/jtw/239.192.251.135:5001 
</LocationMatch>
```

.... till /255/*
First subfolder is IP and last subfolder is the port

Is there any way to do this in one LocationMatch and Proxypassmatch?

Thanks,

Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Apache 2.4.8 onwards, a combination of [1] and [2] can do that:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?<internalIP>\d+)/(?<internalPort>\d+)$">
    ProxysPass http://myserver.com/jtw/239.192.251.%{env:MATCH_INTERNALIP}:%{env:MATCH_INTERNALPORT}
</LocationMatch>
```

[1] https://serverfault.com/questions/423910/is-it-possible-to-get-the-matched-regex-from-within-the-apache-locationmatch-dir

[2] http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#locationmatch